# How to access session data from test?

Tags: perl, testing, mojolicious

The [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/) framework [states](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Testing#Testing-application-helpers) next:

> Any aspect of the application (helpers, plugins, routes, etc.) can be introspected from Test::Mojo through the application object.

But when helper, for example, `$c->current_user` deals with session it fails.

The session data is not available and I can not access it from test:

```
$t->app->session  # {}
```

Thus `$t->app->current_user` fails too.

How to access session data from test?

**UPD** The test

```
use Mojo::Base -strict;

use Mojolicious::Lite;

use Test::More;
use Test::Mojo;

get '/set_session' => sub {
    my $c =  shift;
    $c->session->{ user_id } = 1;
    $c->render( text => $c->session->{ user_id } );
};

get '/get_session' => sub {
    my $c =  shift;
    $c->render( text => $c->session->{ user_id } );
};

my $t = Test::Mojo->new;
$t->get_ok( '/set_session' )->status_is(200);

is $t->app->session->{ user_id }, 1, 'Session available from test script';

$t->get_ok( '/get_session' )->status_is(200)
  ->content_is( 1 );

done_testing();
```

**UPD** test result

```
ok 1 - GET /set_session
ok 2 - 200 OK
not ok 3 - Session available from test script
#   Failed test 'Session available from test script'
#   at t/session.t line 22.
#          got: undef
#     expected: '1'
ok 4 - GET /get_session
ok 5 - 200 OK
ok 6 - exact match for content
1..6
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 6.
```

**UPD**

It seems that `Mojo::Test` object should save session object in addition to [`the request and response objects from the previous transaction`](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Testing#Test::Mojo-at-a-glance)

Comment: Can you provide a runnable test case, please?

Comment: @daxim: test script is applied.

Comment: For simple sessions, session data is stored in the client side in a cookie, which wouldn't be available without a request from the client side with the cookie.

Comment: @Pradeep it doesn't really matter how the session data is stored for what OP is trying to do. He wants to have access to the session for the current user's request at this point of time. The problem with this I believe is that `$t->app` gives you the application object, but not with the context of the most recently completed request. However your comment is very useful, because if it's in the client's cookies, you _can_ read it. `$t->ua` is the client after all, and in the test you directly control it. It is a bit hacky though.

Comment: Indirectly related, I've solved this problem for Catalyst with my module [Test::WWW::Mechanize::Catalyst::WithContext](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::WWW::Mechanize::Catalyst::WithContext). A similar approach might be possible for you, or (as it sometimes is with Mojo in my experience) the solution might be much simpler but not obvious.

Comment: @simbabque: yes, I can decode JWT passed to client, but this solution did not work if session data is stored on server side. Mojo DOC states that `$t is stateful` and I `can introspect any aspect of the application`. As you can see from test: not any aspect...

Comment: You could reach into the data store that the app uses. Since you're running it locally, you have access to it. You can _probably_ use `$t->app->something` to get the session engine to load you a specific session based on the session_id (which you  probably know). I'd have to look into it more.

Comment: @simbabque: Thanks to sri and jberger, they give me an idea. The `$t->app` should not just return bare application. It should initialize the application with context known by `$t`

Comment: @simbabque: you may check the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test helpers in context of last request I write next role:

```
package Test::Mojo::Role::Helper;

use Mojo::Base -role;

sub helper {
    my( $t ) = @_;

    $t->tx->req->cookies( @{ $t->tx->res->cookies } );
    $t->app->build_controller( $t->tx );
}

1;
```

Then use it as next:

```
use Test::Mojo;
my $t = Test::Mojo->with_roles( '+Helper' )->new( 'MyApp' );

$t->post_ok( '/login', json => { contact => $user_c, password => $user_p } )
  ->status_is( 200 );


is $t->helper->uid,       1,  "Authorized user has identificator";
is $t->helper->role, 'user',  "Authorized user has 'user' privilege";
```

**UPD** More robust solution

```
package Test::Mojo::Role::Helper;

use Mojo::Base -role;

my $req_context; # Here is controller object
sub helper { $req_context }


sub hook_context {
    my( $t ) =  @_;

    $t->app->hook( after_dispatch =>  sub{ $req_context =  shift });

    $t;
}

1;
```

The testing is same with next small difference. When application is constructed we should hook to `after_dispatch` event:

```
my $t = Test::Mojo
  ->with_roles( '+Helper' )
  ->new( 'App' )
  ->hook_context;
```

Comment: I'm no expert on Mojo, but both option seem viable. How is the second solution more robust? I'd probably get rid of the role and subclass Test::Mojo locally to work with that. Less boilerplate that way.

Comment: @simbabque: I do not know. jberger said that first solution is ugly.

Comment: I would take Joel's word for it. So I guess your first solution is slow, because it needs to create a controller object every time. Could also be that other things happen in the background, but I am not at all familiar with the Mojo internals. The second solution is not great if you have more than one Test::Mojo instance across your test run. If you start running multiple tests in a single process you'll get in trouble, especially if they go in parallel. I would subclass and make that `$req_context` an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The `Test::Mojo` class does not give you direct access to the session contents. The test class represents a client of your Mojolicious application, and the client does not have direct access to the session cookie either (well, it's just base64-encoded JSON so it's not exactly secret, but still …).

The “proper” way to test the session is to check that the app *behaves* correctly regarding the session, not just to check that the session was set to some value. That's effectively what your `/get_session` endpoint does. Of course you shouldn't just add such an endpoint for testing, but consider how the session fits into your requirements. E.g. as a BDD-style scenario:

```
Feature: the secret page
  there is a secret page that should be only visible to logged-in users.

  Background:
    Given a user "test:test123"
    Given a new client

  Scenario: users cannot see the page when they are not logged in
     When I visit the /secret page
     Then I get a 404 response

  Scenario: users can see the page after logging in
    Given I log in as "test:test123"
     When I visit the /secret page
     Then I see "this is the secret"
```

The `$t->app->session` does not contain the session because the session data is loaded into the controller's `stash`. This only exists for the duration of the request. In particular `app->session` is merely a helper that delegates to the current controller, not a primary method of the application.

If you really need to peek into the session cookie, this might be the least insane way to do it, short of inflating a controller object:

```
my ($session) = grep { $_->name eq $t->app->sessions->cookie_name } $t->ua->cookie_jar->all->@*;
$session = $session->value =~ s/--[^-]+$//r;  # strip signature
$session =~ tr/-/=/;
$session = $t->app->sessions->deserialize->(Mojo::Util::b64_decode $session);
```

Comment: I found different solution. We can `build_controller` for a given context. See answer above.